# Issue with access xml file fro GIT through Spring-cloud

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

Use the Spring cloud based configuration for the application. Using spring-cloud-config-server for the configuration test.

Need to read configurations from simple books.xml file

```
<catalog>
    <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
    </book>
</catalog>
```

Based on the below commit and discussion, reading configurations from xml file from GIT in spring cloud is possible but no test cases available in it.

Also, in the `spring-cloud-config-server/src/test/resources/`* , no xml file present and no examples under  `spring-cloud-config-server/src/test/java/`*

As JUnits read from below file as local repository, need to push the xml file into `spring-cloud-config-server/src/test/resources/config-repo/` and then access it.

```
@Test
public void addTestNewPush() throws Exception {
    String uri = ConfigServerTestUtils.prepareLocalRepo("config-repo");
    this.context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(TestConfiguration.class).web(false)
                                    .run("--spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=" + uri);
    EnvironmentRepository repository = this.context.getBean(EnvironmentRepository.class);
    Environment environment = repository.findOne("bar", "staging", "master");
    Git git = Git.open(ResourceUtils.getFile(uri).getAbsoluteFile());
    Path applicationFilePath = Paths.get("C:/Users/sholalkere/Desktop/books.xml");
    git.add().addFilepattern(".").call();
    git.add().addFilepattern("books.xml").call();
    git.commit().setMessage("Updated for pull").call();
    environment = repository.findOne("catalog", "staging", "master");
    assertEquals("catalog",environment.getPropertySources().get(0).getSource().get("catalog"));
}
```

The push to git is not working. What is the wrong here??

Comment: Two things: 1) "push to git is not working" isn't helpful. Any errors? What happens? 2) I've only used jgit for read operations, I I won't be able to help with push, but why do you need to push?

Comment: 1) "push to git is not working" isn't helpful. Any errors? What happens? . --> when I see in config-repo - file did not added as a part of git. Though the Junit testcase was successful. 2) I've only used jgit for read operations - There are read operations for .properties, .yaml file but not for .xml file. As say books.xml is not present in confi-repo to read. First push the fie to git and then read from it.